# How to make sql insert statement in asp.net using vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Im currently do my internship and this company use asp.net language . Its quite new for me because before this i never use asp.net . So i need help from all of you . I already try to write the code but its seems to many error . this is my code :

[This is my HTML Code](http://pastebin.com/27gjPSkr)

[This is my code behind](http://pastebin.com/SqLB0K9c)

Comment: Your "Response.Write" has semi-colon.

Comment: But my textbox name not declared . i dont know why

Comment: Have you considered using the <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" /> control instead? It will give you access to Login1_Authenticate, Login1_LoggedIn, etc. methods to do your authentication.

Comment: @SollyM but then i dont know why my textbox doesnt work . it say its doesnt declare . can you help ?

Comment: Firstly try using the Login control and see if it registers. Then customize the control and the child controls must register too. If not, then we can look at it from there.

Comment: @SollyM but then i need to make the register form working first before use login control

Comment: @Xay, email me[at]sollym.co.za and I will help you. We will bring back the answer here when we are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this example. See if it works for you.
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-User-Registration-Form-Example-in-ASPNet.aspx

Unfortunately I can't bring the entire code to this page. Hope this helps.

Comment: awesome. glad to be of help.